# Origin of 'Son of a Gun'

Tags: british-english, slang

According to the OED a 'son of a gun' was a child born to a woman who accompanied her husband on a Royal Navy gunship. However I distinctly remember hearing on a BBC Radio 4 history programme that the 'sons of guns' were children born to 'ladies of easy virtue' with whom British sailors frequented in foreign ports. They would be allowed on to any subsequent ship to give birth, which happened on the gun-deck between the guns, and the ship's doctor would attend them. As no one took responsibility for fatherhood the child would be known as a 'son of a gun'. Wikipaedia is clearly unsure concerning these two possible origins. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: I trust the OED a lot more than Wikipedia, which can be - and is - edited by anyone.

Comment: We have that problem here too.

Comment: I suspect mere rhyme-driven euphemism, followed by backsplanation. FWIW, it's been [asked here before](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37211/origin-of-son-of-a-gun).

Comment: @Tyler James Young. Please could you say that again but in English this time.

Comment: With many people seeking to avoid the harshness of other "son of a..." variants, a simple rhyming alternative grew popular. Perhaps, in addition to rhyming, it was just far enough removed from the originals to be palatable but still have a little bit of a bite to it. As it pervaded the parlance, people came up with various explanations for its origin, each one perfectly plausible but perhaps none so accurate as "it was more fun to say in public than a swear." My suspicions arose thusly reading the previous iteration of this question and it's accompanying answers.

Answer (score 0):

- it can mean "born on a gunship" - unusual nowadays
- but it is more commonly used as an humorous compliment, something like "you are terrific"

Answer (score 0):

When I asked my father this 50 years ago, he said it was a slang term for a child of unknown paternal lineage due to the mother's profession involving paid companionship provided to British Navy enlisted men during port calls.

Comment: It's not called "British Navy". It's the Royal Navy.

Comment: And whilst we are on that subject, it is not called the 'British Pound' either (as I repeatedly find on this site). It is the 'Pound Sterling'.